# python - smallest number of groupings of lists which are disjointed derived from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, graph, theory

from a nestedList, I have to group this lists in the smallest number of groups possible with all lists in the group without intersection with each other. Then the groups also shouldn't have intersection meaning each list from the nested list should appear only once in all the groups.
e.g.

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,7],[52,12,1],[91239,21,1],[3,5,6],[6,8,10]]
[1,2,3],[4,5,7],[6,8,10]
[52,12,1],[3,5,6]
[91239,21,1]
```

Furthermore, groups should be labeled with numbers using dictionary. using 1-10, i have to use the least number of numbers possible, so if i call *groupings* the values of keys should be equal most of the time `{[1,2,3]:'1',[4,5,7]:'1',[6,8,10]:'1', [52,12,1]:'2',[3,5,6]:'2', [91239,21,1]:'3'}`

There is a larger list which I am working on right now and has so far come up with this:

```
    def disjoint(a, b):
         for i in a:
            if i in b:
                return False
         return True

    numberassignments = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
    groupings = {}
    for i in numberassignments:
        for j in range(len(list)):
            if list[j] not in groupings:
                groupings[list[j]] = i
                for k in range(list):
                    if disjoint(list[j], list[k]) and list[k] not in groupings:
                        grouped = [l for l in groupings if groupings[l] == i]
                        if all(disjoint(m, list[k]) for m in grouped):
                            groupings[list[k]] = i
```

so far my code is able to group the lists with no intersection, my problem is, I have no idea whether it is grouped the least amount possible or even how to code which optimizes the number of groups. those i asked told me it should have something to do with graph theory which I have absolutely no idea about (i did grasp that vertices are the lists, edges are their intersections but what do i do with this knowledge?).
contraints: no libraries

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. so, whats the question?

Comment: lol was my newbie aura emanating too much? How do i know when the groupings are the least amount possible? I have to minimize the amount of groupings, how do i do this?

Comment: Please post your question with clear explanation, input and expected output. Its messy.